# Change text on default fields in PayPal?

Tags: php, button, paypal, customization, dynamically-generated

Is there any way (**without using Express Checkout**) to change the default text of "Item total" on the Order Summary PayPal payment page?

Referring **only to the image** on my previous question: [Adding item total to PayPal's order summary, for full aggregate cart payment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185271/adding-item-total-to-paypals-order-summary-for-full-aggregate-cart-payment/15187987?noredirect=1#15187987)

I'm referring only to the image because I'm simply not using cart upload now. I am instead using the ButtonManagerAPI to dynamically create buttons with the right total cart price. All I'm trying to do now is change the text of `Item total` on the payment page to `Total` or if possible, just remove the `item total` field? Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible with (Website) Payments Standard (nor Express Checkout, mind you).

We don't currently support the changing of various parts of text within our checkout area except for those expressly designed as such, such as the `BRANDNAME` parameter in Express Checkout).