# Customizing sandbox.paypal "Order summary"

Tags: wordpress, paypal, sandbox

I am facing a problem regarding sandbox.paypal payment system. I have successfully developed a WordPress plugin where I accept payments from the users via sandbox.paypal. On doing so, I want to customize the labels of Order Summary.

Attachment link: http://prnt.sc/e0w40y.

I just want to edit "item name" to "product name", similarly "Quantity" to "Numbers". How can I do that?
Anyone please!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change text on default fields in PayPal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320950/change-text-on-default-fields-in-paypal)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was wondering if there is a way to add custom labels and show custom values generated by plugin. Can I add "Travelers" label and show the value generated by plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Regret to say, this is not possible to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was wondering if there is a way to add custom labels and show custom values generated by plugin. Can I add "Travelers" label and show the value generated by plugin?

Comment: Are you using Website Payment Standard (WPS) or Express Checkout? If you are using WPS you can use custom variable or if with Express Checkout you can use PAYMENTREQUEST_n_CUSTOM.

EC : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/ (search over PAYMENTREQUEST_n_CUSTOM)

WPS : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/ (search for custom)